# App works in canvas page but not in page tab

Tags: facebook, access-token, userid

So im working on an app which will where you will be able to send in a love poem and then get it back to your facebook wall translated.

So it should be a pretty simple task. I ask for the access_token and user_id: THen they fill out a form and send it to me.

The problem that I first experienced some problems with a redirection when i moved the app in to a page tab.

What has happened now is that we no longer get the username of the "client" when he is on our fan page, though he is when he is visiting the app....

therefore a wounder. what could this depend upon:

here is my code:

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Febuary Love app
*/
?>

<?php

require ('fb-php-sdk/facebook.php');

//Create facebook application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
 ));

//get user- if present, insert/update access_token for this user
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user){
  try {
    $userData = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    die("API call failed");
  }
  $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
}
else {
echo "Please login...<br />";
    $my_redir_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Copypanthers/131063547012851?sk=app_286456534743923';
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=user_about_me,publish_stream,offline_access&client_id=286456534743923&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_redir_url);
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

echo $user;

//create authorising url
if(!$user){
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'offline_access,publish_stream',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/february_love'

  ));
}


if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

  // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
  if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
  } else {
    echo 'Please enter the Poem name';
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
  } else {
    echo 'Please enter some notes';
  }

  $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
  $access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];

  // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
  $new_post = array(
  'post_title'  =>  $title,
  'post_content'  =>  $description,
  'post_category'  =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
  'tags_input'  =>  array($tags),
  'post_status'  =>  'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
  'post_type'  =>  'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
  'access_token' => $access_token,
  'user' => $user,
  );

  //SAVE THE POST
  $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
  add_post_meta($pid, 'access_token', $access_token, true);
  add_post_meta($pid, 'user', $user, true);


    //SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY
  wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

  //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
  $link = get_permalink( $pid );
  wp_redirect();

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

get_header(); ?> 

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
                    <div class="form-content">                      
            <!-- WINE RATING FORM -->
            <div class="wpcf8">
              <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>" target="_top">
                <div id="steps-app">
                <div id="step1">
                  <img src="https://www.copypanthers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/step1.png">
                  <p>First <em>allow</em> the app so we can send you the translated poem</p>
                </div>
                <div id="app_center">
                  <img src="https://www.copypanthers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/accept_app.png">
                </div>
                <div id="step2">
                  <img src="https://www.copypanthers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/step2.png">
                  <p>Then send us the poem or message</p>
                </div>
                <div id="arrow">
                  <img src="https://www.copypanthers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/narrow.png">
                </div>
              </div></a>
              <div class="content-app">
               <?php the_content(); ?>
              <h2>Share some February Love!</h2>
              <p>Although the 14th of February should be dedicated to your loved one, we think that friends, bosses or favorite co-workers deserve some affection, too. <br/><br/>So until the 13th of February we will translate a poem or message from you to them <em>for free</em>. We will also reward 2 writers with a special <em>Valentine’s Day gift.</em><br/><br/> </p>


            <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <!-- post name -->
              <fieldset name="name">
                <label for="title">Title of your poem or message:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="5" name="title" />
              </fieldset>

              <!--<fieldset class="dedication">
                <label for="dedication">Dedicated to (all my co-workers for example):</label>
                <input type="text" value="" tabindex="10" id="dedication" name="dedication" />
              </feildset> -->

              <!-- post Category -->
              <fieldset class="category">
                <label for="cat">Translate to:</label>
                <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
              </fieldset>

              <!-- post Content -->
              <fieldset class="content">
                <label for="description">Love poem:</label>
                <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="70" rows="5"></textarea>
              </fieldset>

              <!-- post tags -->
              <fieldset class="tags">
                <label for="post_tags"></label>
                <input type="hidden" value="" tabindex="35" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" />
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" />
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="access_token">
                <label for="access_token"></label>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $access_token;?>" id="access_token" name="access_token" />
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="user">
                <label for="user"></label>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user;?>" id="user" name="user" />
              </fieldset>

              <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
              <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
            </form>
            </div><!-- END content-app -->
            </div> <!-- END WPCF7 -->

                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </div><!-- #post-## --> 

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

tanks for taking time.

Best regards

Comment: I find this statement odd:  "_What has happened now is that we no longer get the username of the "client" when he is on our fan page_".  How in the world were you ever able to get someone's username using your code solely because they were your page fan? That sounds like a huge security hole.

Comment: Posting that much code is generally a bad idea.  People will not be too willing to sift through all of the code there.  It would be preferable to include only the crucial parts that you have found to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is in a page's tab,  you will receive a [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).  This `signed_request` will contain [some of] the users information after you decode it (see the link above for details).  Once you have decoded the `signed_request` you will be able to extract the users id.  From there it is a matter of querying the Graph API to retrieve the users (public) info which should include their name.  The query would look something like this :

```
 $facebook->api('/USER_ID');
```

Even for a user that has not authenticated your application you should be able to retrieve this minimal data :

```
{
  "id": "123", 
  "name": "'John Skeet", 
  "first_name": "'John", 
  "last_name": "Skeet", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "locale": "en_UK", 
  "updated_time": "2012-01-30T01:09:29+0000", 
  "type": "user"
}
```